# jacobi iterative method has wrong answer in c++

Tags: c++, math, linear-algebra, physics, scientific-computing

I'm writing Jacobi iterative method to solve any linear system of equations. this program works for some examples but doesn't work for others. for example for

```
A=     and B=
7  3       5
2  3       4
```

this will works and answers are true but for

```
A=     and B=
1  2       3
3  4       7
```

the answers are wrong and huge numbers.
I really don't know what should I do to make a correct calculation.
I used some other codes but still I have this issue with codes.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double A[10][10], alpha[10][10], B[10], betha[10], x[10][100], sum[10];
    int i, j, n, k, kmax;
    cout << "insert number of equations \n";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "insert LHS of equations (a11,a12,...,ann)\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++){
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "A=\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++){
            cout << A[i][j] << "\t\t";
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    cout << "alpha=\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++){
            if (i == j){
                alpha[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else{
                alpha[i][j] = -A[i][j] / A[i][i];
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++){
            cout << alpha[i][j] << "\t\t";
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    cout << "insert RHS of equations";
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        cin >> B[i];
    }
    cout << "\nbetha=\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        betha[i] = B[i] / A[i][i];
        cout << betha[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "Enter the number of repetitions." << endl;
    cin >> kmax;
    k = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        sum[i] = 0;
        x[i][k] = betha[i];    //initial values 
    }
    for (k = 0; k <= kmax; k++){
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j++){
                sum[i] += alpha[i][j] * x[j][k];
            }
            x[i][k] = betha[i] + sum[i];
            sum[i] = 0; 
        }
    }
    cout << "answers:\n\n";
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        cout << x[i][kmax] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, you got down-vote(s) and close flag(s) but I will provide a hint instead: Check your implementation step-wise in the debugger with input values from which you know they yield the wrong result. Have a look at intermediate values and check whether/when they start to differ from expected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix, in row order, is: [{1, 2} {3, 4}]

It has determinant equal to -2; clearly it's not singular.

It has inverse: [{4, -2}, {-3, 1}]/(-2)

The correct solution is: {1, 1}

You can verify this by substituting back into the original equation and checking to make sure you have an identity: [{1, 2} {3, 4}]{1, 1} = {3, 7}

Iterative methods can be sensitive to initial conditions.

The point about diagonally dominant is correct.  Perhaps a more judicious choice of initial condition, closer to the right answer, would allow you to converge.

Update:

Jacobi iteration decomposes the matrix into diagonal elements D and off-diagonal elements R:

[image]

Jacobi will converge if:

[image: Convergence criteria]

Since this is not the case for the first row of your sample matrix, you might have a problem.

You still get there in a single step if you use the correct answer as your initial guess.  This says that even Jacobi will work with a judicious choice.

If I start with {1, 1} I converge to the correct answer in a single iteration.

Comment: I’m very glad. It made me happy to think about your problem, so thanks for asking.  Why not vote the answer up and accept if it helped you?

Comment: Because both of the answers helped me and I can't choose only one of them.

Comment: If you solve the system anyway the hard way, why would you care to add a trivial Jacobi iteration on top of it? What if an exact solution  can not be found due to floating point limitations, the Jacobi-iteration will then move away from the most exact numerical solution.

Comment: It's only an example to demonstrate how initial choice can affect converge.  If one can't be found, and you guessed badly, you won't converge.  I would try another initial guess having the information I provided.  I am not suggesting that the user add Jacobi iteration on top of a known solution.  Keep up.

Comment: I agree, the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel iterative methods only work for system of equations that the coefficient of main diagonal must be bigger than other coefficient and this condition can be find rarely. First I thought it is possible to converge a diverse matrix but when I tried to make it on paper it was impossible. I think the most exact way is using inverted matrix, I was trying to write program of this method but the determinant calculation is hard in general mode. I think I should study more about numerical methods to solve system of equations.

Comment: Not an inverted matrix.  Go read about LU decomposition with pivoting.  It's a workhorse algorithm.  You can solve systems with millions of degrees of freedom with it.  I used to make a living doing it.

Comment: Sure I read about it. I'm really glad to have a conversation with you. Thank you for your information.

Answer (score 1):

You should again check the condition for convergence. There you will find that usually the method only converges for diagonally dominant matrices. The first example satisfies that condition, while the second violates it clearly.

If convergence is not guaranteed, divergence might happen, as you found.

---

More specifically, the Jacobi iteration in the second example computes

```
xnew[0] = (3 - 2*x[1])/1;
xnew[1] = (7 - 3*x[0])/4;
```

Over two iterations the composition of steps gives

```
xtwo[0] = (3 - 2*xnew[1])/1 = -0.5 + 1.5*x[0];
xtwo[1] = (7 - 3*xnew[0])/4 = -0.5 + 1.5*x[1];
```

which is clearly expanding the initial errors with factor `1.5`.

Comment: So Jacobi iterative method only works for converge matrices, the biggest number in every row must be in main diagonal to converges the alpha matrix. thank you.